# Make a logout button show up when someone is logged in?

Tags: php, authentication, logout

Is there a way to make a logout button appear on all pages of my website when a user is logged in and not there if someone isn't logged in? I'm assuming some sort of php would do the trick, but I'm not sure.  I'm sort of new to all of this so if you could give a detailed explanation it would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it by starting new session and setup a session variable.

at login file do it like

```
<?php 
session_start();
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {

$username = trim(htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])));
$password = trim(htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])));
if (!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    echo "<br/> welcome ", $username;
    echo "<br/><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";

     } else {
    echo "Please enter correct username or password";
     }   
} else {
echo "Go to login page</br>";
echo "<a href='login.php'>Login</a>";
}
```

and every page check for that session variable

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    echo "you logged in as </br>", $_SESSION['username'];
    echo "<br/><a href='logout.php'>logout</a>";
}else{
//your page stuff
}
```

and to logout, destroy the session

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
   session_destroy();
   echo "<br> you are logged out successufuly!";
} 
   echo "<br/><a href='login.php'>login</a>";
 ?>
```

//don't forget to read more about session and cookies.

Answer (score 3):

- Create $_SESSION['user'] and fill it when user is loged in.
- create a php page that you will include in all your pages ,in this page check if a session variable $_SESSION['user'] is set or not,and show the link according to this condition

  ```
   if(isset($_SESSION["user"])){ /*your logout button*/ } else { /*your login button*/ }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into session management?
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Answer (score 0):

This is an example, there are other ways:

When the user logs in, create a `$_SESSION['user']` variable.

When you want to show the logout button, check if the session variable is set or not with `isset($_SESSION['user'])`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['uid']))
{
      if (!empty($_SESSION['uid']))
      {
        echo "<input type='button' value='Logout' onclick='logout_function();' />";
      }
}
```

Saludos xD

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
if(!empty($_SESSION["user"]))
{
/*
* logout button
*/
}
else
{
/*
* login code
*/
}
```